# ActiveSheet.SaveAs only saves first worksheet - multiple times, but only on some machines

Tags: vba, excel

The following VBA snippet works correctly on one machine with Excel version
"Microsoft(R) Office Excel(R) 2007 (12.0.6727.5000) SP3 MSO (12.0.6728.5000)"
but not on one with
"Microsoft(R) Office Excel(R) 2007 (12.0.6729.5000) SP3 MSO (12.0.6728.5000)"

Breaking and single-stepping indicates that the wSheet is iterating over the known worksheets, but the exported files only contain the contents of the first worksheet -  i.e. sheet1.csv, sheet2.csv, sheet3.csv are all saved, but each one contains the contents of sheet1 from the workbook.

A separate "macro" that only saves the active worksheet behaves identically - no matter which worksheet is active at the time the "macro" is invoked, only the data from the first worksheet is saved, though into a file named as the active worksheet. The DBPrint statement also shows that the wSheet is iterating over the worksheets. (DBPrint is just a Debug.Print with an on/off switch.)

```
  For Each wSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    wSheet.Activate
    wSheetName = wSheet.Name
    SaveAsName = wBookName & "." & wSheetName & ".csv"
    DBPrint "saving as " & SaveAsName
    On Error Resume Next
      wSheet.SaveAs filename:=SaveAsName, FileFormat:=xlCSV
      ' ... error handling code (no errors reported, though)
    On Error GoTo 0
  Next wSheet
```

Comment: From your break and single-stepping, I assume this won't find anything useful, but do you mind trying this? After `On Error Resume Next`, put `Msgbox wSheet.Name` and make sure that it says the expected name each time? Sorry, that's just where I would start if it was my own code.

Comment: Thank you, puzzlepiece87. The Msgbox reported the correct sheet names for all sheets exported, but only the content of the first is still actually exported.

Comment: Ah, then I have no idea what else the problem could be (unless it's something to do with .csv files, which I never use), but I'm posting a workaround answer.

Comment: By the way, do you set `wBookName` anywhere?

Comment: It might also be breaking because you're using ActiveWorkbook.

Comment: Came back because someone upvoted my answer - upon further review, I am pretty sure this is happening because saving a multi-sheet workbook as .csv will only save the first sheet, regardless of which is active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My workaround:

```
Dim Workbook1 As Workbook

Set Workbook1 = ActiveWorkbook
For Each wSheet In Workbook1.Sheets
    SaveAsName = wBookName & "." & wSheet.Name & ".csv"
    DBPrint "saving as " & SaveAsName
    wSheet.Copy After:=Workbook1.Sheets(Workbook1.Sheets.Count)
    Workbook1.Sheets(Workbook1.Sheets.Count).Move
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=SaveAsName, FileFormat:=xlCSV
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Next wSheet
```

Try that and let me know if it works.

Comment: Wow! that works! Thank you. It seems it moves the active worksheet to the "front of the queue", then saves it. It still saves only the first worksheet, but now that is the correct one. Thank you much.

Comment: Exactly. You can probably already tell, but the `.Move` command moves a sheet to a new workbook. I know you want your original workbook intact when you finish, so I make a `.Copy` first and then move that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and, for a while, used @puzzlepiece's workaround. It worked well but became a bit slow as the datasets I have to use became bigger.

Luckily, I found a fix that does not require copying and moving: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/628-excel-split-workbook.html

```
Sub Splitbook()
'Updateby20140612
Dim xPath As String
xPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    xWs.Copy
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\" & xWs.Name & ".xlsx"
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```